# C# unit test Temporary files and folders

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I am coming into C# from Java.

I am looking to test my Lucene .net functionality. I'd like to use an on disk lucene index for reading and writing in those tests.

In java I could use TemporaryFolder with junit, which would create a temporary a folder, that I could use for the tests, somewhere on the system, and then clear it once the tests were done.

What's the procedure for this kind testing in C#?

Edit: when I create the project in VS I choose "Unit Test Project (.NET Framework)" The latest one 4.7.1 I think...

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you looking to use? There are quite a few different ones and they'll each have slightly different ways of structuring setup/teardown style actions.

Comment: answered in edit